# how to deploy web application and web service in glassfish server

Tags: web-services, web-applications, glassfish-3, web-deployment-project

I want to deploy web application and web service in a glassfish server . How can I do it?
can I deploy two applications on different port? I can't combine the web application and RESTful web service.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Web apps and Jersey web services are both deployed in WARs. So, you have several options.

You can combine the two in to a single web app, and deploy a single WAR.

You can deploy them in separate WARs, with separate contexts (i.e. /war1, /ws2).

You can create a new virtual server (which can listen on any port) and one WAR to each, and then they can both be using the same context, they're just use different hosts and/or ports.

It's not clear what problem you're having or what you're trying to do, but those are the three main options available to you.

Comment: hi will, i can't combine the web service and web application. coz i delete the context root name and resource name in web.xml in web service.If web application use admin port 4848 and 8080. Can I use admin port 4848 to create new domain or new virtual server or host/ports. And Do you have any code or website for reference thanks

Comment: You should amend your question with more details about what you have, what you've tried, and what you're looking for.